# Retrieving the field names from sitecore item

Tags: sitecore

While I am searching the keyword in sitecore using sitecore.seach it returns the item name(where it is located) for the search keyword. Is there any option to get the field name along the item?

I use the following code:

```cs
using (IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
   SearchHits hits = context.Search(searchString, new SearchContext(SiteRoot));
   var results = hits.FetchResults(0, 100);

   foreach (SearchResult result in results)
   {
      try
      {
         Item item = result.GetObject<Item>();
         if (item != null)
         {
            results.AddResultToCategory(result, categoryName);
         }
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to find out the exact fields (field names) where the search string was found, right?

If that's the case, then you should get a collection of item fields (`item.Fields`), and iterate through it checking for the search string in the field value.

As far as I know, the Sitecore Search shell application works the same way when displaying results: the item is taken form the `SearchResult`, and the field collection is just iterated looking for the hit using simple `text.IndexOf()` comparison.

And I'm not aware about a different way to accomplish this.